# Missing getImage method on Plone Dexterity image content?

Tags: plone, dexterity

Attributes available on a **Dexterity Content Type** with `Image Field`:

```
>>> app.Plone.test.image.
app.Plone.test.image.__class__(         app.Plone.test.image.__provides__(      app.Plone.test.image._height            app.Plone.test.image._p_state
app.Plone.test.image.__delattr__(       app.Plone.test.image.__reduce__(        app.Plone.test.image._p_activate(       app.Plone.test.image._setData(
app.Plone.test.image.__dict__           app.Plone.test.image.__reduce_ex__(     app.Plone.test.image._p_changed         app.Plone.test.image._width
app.Plone.test.image.__doc__            app.Plone.test.image.__repr__(          app.Plone.test.image._p_deactivate(     app.Plone.test.image.contentType
app.Plone.test.image.__format__(        app.Plone.test.image.__setattr__(       app.Plone.test.image._p_delattr(        app.Plone.test.image.data
app.Plone.test.image.__getattribute__(  app.Plone.test.image.__setstate__(      app.Plone.test.image._p_estimated_size  app.Plone.test.image.filename
app.Plone.test.image.__getstate__(      app.Plone.test.image.__sizeof__(        app.Plone.test.image._p_getattr(        app.Plone.test.image.getFirstBytes(
app.Plone.test.image.__hash__(          app.Plone.test.image.__str__(           app.Plone.test.image._p_invalidate(     app.Plone.test.image.getImageSize(
app.Plone.test.image.__implemented__(   app.Plone.test.image.__subclasshook__(  app.Plone.test.image._p_jar             app.Plone.test.image.getSize(
app.Plone.test.image.__init__(          app.Plone.test.image.__weakref__        app.Plone.test.image._p_mtime           app.Plone.test.image.open(
app.Plone.test.image.__module__         app.Plone.test.image._blob              app.Plone.test.image._p_oid             app.Plone.test.image.openDetached(
app.Plone.test.image.__new__(           app.Plone.test.image._data              app.Plone.test.image._p_serial          app.Plone.test.image.size
app.Plone.test.image.__providedBy__(    app.Plone.test.image._getData(          app.Plone.test.image._p_setattr(
```

I would expect a method `getImage` or `getImageURL` method to be present… so much so that I found myself working around its absence via the following:

```
def get_image(self):
    return "data:%s;base64,%s" % (self.context.image.contentType,
        base64.encodestring(self.context.image.data))
```

And:

```
<img tal:attributes="src view/get_image" />
```

Which works, but is not ideal in many (hopefully obvious) ways. Now, the default view of this type provides the desired functionality via a *widget resource*:

```
view/++widget++form.widgets.image/@@download/the-image.png
```

But I don't have access to it (AFAICT) because I've customized the *default view* of this type. Should there be a `getImage` method? Or am I missing some other obvious approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried it in plone.app.imagescales-way

```
<img tal:replace="structure context/@@images/shortnameofmyfield/thumb" />
```

Comment: That works, thank you! (I didn't get the @@images memo apparently.)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved a similar issue like this:

```
selected_image.restrictedTraverse("@@images").scale('image', width=None, height=None).index_html()
```

This returns the image in its original size.